# How to call Odoo data from JSON controller?

Tags: python, json, controller, odoo, odoo-12

So I need to make a Rest service which will call data from an specific model.

In order to do this, I must create a controller.

I'm newbie with Odoo, also with Json, and I can't find anything that could work for this.

Far I have is all I need but in a http request.

```
class RestService(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/orders/<model("sale.order"):order>', auth='none', website=True)
    def consulta_orden(self , order):
        return request.render('consulta_pedidos.order', {'order': order})
        
        return {'order_id': order_id}
```

The idea is that when I hace the data loaded, I can render this data in a template. Already did this with an Http request, but I need it with Json.
Any tip about how to implement it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem in a very simple way.

The code:

```
@http.route(['/orden_detalle', '/orden_detalle/<int:order_id>'], type='json', auth='user')
    def orden_detalle(self, order_id=None):
        if order_id:
            domain = [('id', '=', order_id)]
        else:
            domain = []
        sales_rec = request.env['sale.order'].search(domain)
        sales = []
        for rec in sales_rec:
            vals = {
                'id': rec.id,
                'name': rec.name,
                'partner_id': rec.partner_id.name,
                'user_id': rec.user_id.name,
            }
            sales.append(vals)
        data = {'status': 200, 'response': sales, 'message': 'Sale(s) returned'}
        return data
```

My source:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGvuRbCyytk
2. Another of my questions: [How to get specific record in json controller in Odoo 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63624527/how-to-get-specific-record-in-json-controller-in-odoo-12)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return Json (for a REST-API) you just need to return it in a Response object.

Make sure you have `Response` imported from `odoo.http`.
Then you can return the json data like this:

```py
return Response(json.dumps({'order_id': order_id}), status=200, content_type="application/json")
```

I usually wrap this logic in a separate function (outside of the controller) that logs the request and response on the Odoo object that is updated, and then returns the Response object.
That way it can also be easily reused in Error handling (where you can then return a custom error response in Json format)

EDIT: also make sure you're not including `Content-Type: application/json` in the request, in that case Odoo will think it's a JSON-RPC request.

Comment: Already tried that but in Postman I'm receiving 404.

Comment: try adding `type="http"` to your `@http.route()`

Also: make sure you're NOT including Content-Type "application/json" as a header in your postman request. If you do, Odoo will try to treat it as a JSON-RPC call (which is what `type="json"` is for), which is not what you want.
Postman usually adds the Content-Type automatically, you might want to change it to something else like `application/rest`
Does that help?

Comment: Nothing working, anyway thanks for your comments. I'm a little bit stressed trying to figure it out how I can make it works. I've searched for some example codes but there's nothing on the web. Thanks agains

Comment: `@http.route(["/api/lead"], type="http", auth="http_basic", csrf=False, methods=["POST"])`
This is what I have as my website route, and that seems to work for me, with Content-Type "application/rest" in postman, Why do you have website=True in your definition?
Also try removing that `<model("sale.order"):order>` from the Url and replace it with `<int:order_id>`, maybe that helps?

Comment: It's possible that the 404 is because it can't find the sale.order