# How to get specific record in json controller in Odoo 12

Tags: python, json, controller, odoo, odoo-12

My question says it all.
I already did a controller to search all records from specific model.

Now I want to search just one record (by its id) from the same model.

My controller for all records is this:

```
@http.route('/get_sales', type='json', auth='user')
    def get_sales(self):
        sales_rec = request.env['sale.order'].search([])
        sales = []
        for rec in sales_rec:
            vals = {
                'id': rec.id,
                'name': rec.name,
                'partner_id': rec.partner_id,
            }
            sales.append(vals)
        data = {'status': 200, 'response': sales, 'message': 'All sales returned'}
        return data
```

So, what I have to add to get just one record depending on its ID.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the browse method, there is an example in the [project](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/project/controllers/rating.py#L82) module. Check the [URLs and Routing](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/website.html#urls-and-routing) if you need to use the converter patterns.

Comment: use `/get-sale/<int:order_id>` as the route, 
add `order_id` as a parameter to `get_sales`, 
use `sale_order = request.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)` to get the SO

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change your controller route like so:

```
@http.route(['/get_sales', '/get_sales/<int:order_id>'], type='json', auth='user')
```

By doing that you now have the option to call your route with or without an `order_id`.

Secondly, change your method like so:

```
def get_sales(self, order_id=None):
```

Now you can add some logic into your method:

```
if order_id:
    domain = [('id', '=', order_id)]
else:
    domain = []
sales_rec = request.env['sale.order'].search(domain)
```

Comment: All answers were very similar, but yours was very complete so I'll accept this one. Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

`sale_rec = request.env['sale.order'].search([('id','=',YOURID)])`

or

`sale_rec = request.env['sale.order'].browse(YOURID)`

Both return the selected object

Comment: Thanks for your answer.